# Can't return a Bitmap object in this function

Tags: .net, vb.net, graphics, bitmap, gdi+

I'm trying to write a function that should create a new bitmap of the specified size and fill it with a specified color, the problem is I'm getting an exception all the time when trying to assign the bitmap to any property or use it in other several ways like getting the bitmap from a dictionary type to read the bitmap properties.

For example this, don't works:

```
Private Shadows Sub Shown() Handles MyBase.Shown

    PictureBox1.BackgroundImage =
        CreateSolidBitmap(New Size(16, 16), Color.Red)

End Sub
```

And this works until the moment that I try to read the bitmap

```
    Private Shadows Sub Shown() Handles MyBase.Shown

        Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of Color, Bitmap) From
            {
                {Color.Red, CreateSolidBitmap(New Size(16, 16), Color.Red)}
            }

        ' This throws the same exception above:
        MsgBox(dict(Color.Red).Size.Width)

    End Sub
```

The exception says this:

> System.ArgumentException was unhandled Message: An unhandled exception
>   of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll
>   Additional information: Invalid parameter.

This is the function, what I'm missing?

```
''' <summary>
''' Creates a bitmap filled with a solid color.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="FillColor">Color to fill the Bitmap.</param>
''' <returns>System.Drawing.Bitmap.</returns>
Private Function CreateSolidBitmap(ByVal Size As Size,
                                   ByVal FillColor As Color) As Bitmap

    ' Create a bitmap.
    Using bmp As New Bitmap(Size.Width, Size.Height)

        ' Create a graphics object.
        Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)

            ' Create a brush using the specified color.
            Using br As New SolidBrush(FillColor)

                ' Fill the graphics object with the brush.
                g.FillRectangle(br, 0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height)

            End Using ' br

        End Using ' g

        Return bmp

    End Using ' bmp

End Function
```

The bitmaps was for this:

[image]

Comment: you are disposing of the same bitmap you are trying to store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not for nothing, but there **IS** a way to optimize this sort of scheme.  I have an app that will store up to 120 images of a size unknown upfront.  I also have to create/manage a thumnbnail of that image.  Rather than storing bitmaps which are enormous, save the image to a stream encoded as PNG:

```
Private Sub EncodeImage(ByVal bmp As Bitmap)
    ' raw bitmaps are HUGE - 1080p can be 8MB while JPG is 400K and PNG is 2MB

   ' optional: examine bmp and make a reasonable size thumbnail.
   ' e.g. store 1080p as a max of 1600x900 or whatever.
   'you can always restore the size

   ' a backing field in the class this procedure is in
    _MS = New MemoryStream

   bmp.Save(mMS, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
End Sub
```

Decoding is simple:

```
_MS.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)

Return System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(mMS, True, False)
```

You can save oodles and oodles of memory this way, there is a slight performance hit if the same image is accessed repeatedly (like in a loop).  There is no reason to resort to something like this for 16x16 **one-color** bitmaps (OP), I wouldnt even store the bitmap in that case.  But from the comment (`5000px bitmap`) I would consider it depending on what these are.

There can also be a quality hit from the encoding (which is a reason to prefer PNG to JPG).  For **one color** bimtmaps, you arent going to notice.  For actual images, you might, but the tradeoff is storing far fewer images in the app, or going even slower by using disk temp files.

HTH

Comment: `for 16x16 one-color bitmaps (OP), I wouldnt even store the bitmap in that case` yes really they are only 16px size, it is for display a kind of Most-Recent-Used colors in a contextmenu as dropdown items, but if you wouldn't even store the bitmap in that case then I supose that you are talking about directly drawing rectangles or what other idea you mean?  well thanks for your time!

Comment: As usual, the devil is in the (implementation) details: for a MRU/CTM, yes I might save the image.  from the OP, it looked like you might be storing a whole bunch of one-color bmps. Draw/Fill rect though has the advantage of not having to track and dispose things and it is not all that slow.  All the ColorPicker controls out there draw ALL the colors that way. It was hard to tell what you were after with the 5000px comment.  Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
Using bmp As New Bitmap(Size.Width, Size.Height)
```

to

```
Dim bmp As New Bitmap(Size.Width, Size.Height)
```

When the `End Using` (of the bmp) is hit, the `bmp` will be disposed.

Comment: but If I use dim then my function will not dispose any of the new bitmaps..increasing the memory.

Comment: Bitmap is a class, and therefore a reference type. If you dispose of it it won't around to reference later.

Comment: @ElektroStudios What? If so, remove everything inside the sub and return `CType(Nothing, Bitmap)`.

Comment: I don't understand this part... if I don't dispose the object that the function generates then in only 10 calls to create a bitmap of 5000px the memory usage (by the new bitmaps that the function creates and don't disposes...) is increased in 200 mb, so how is supposed that I need to do this?

Comment: @ElektroStudios that is a result of storing X number of bitmaps in a Dictionary.  Since you have the function to create them, consider creating them as needed and disposing of them when done with them.\